# C struct is only working when there is a printf with declarative method

Tags: c, pointers, struct, printf

Let's say I have a struct declared in a temp.h as follows:

```
/* physical memory */
typedef struct pmem_struct {
 uint32_t val;
} pmem_s, *pmem_p;
```

And lets say I declare this struct in my temp.c file in the method pmem_p pmem_new() like so:

```
 pmem_p pmem_new() {
  pmem_s pmems;
  pmem_p pmem = &pmems;
  pmem->val = 0;
  //printf(stderr, "From Mem: %x\n", pmem->val);
  return pmem;
}
```

Now here is my main.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "temp.h"
#include "gen.h"

int main() {
    pmem_p pmem = pmem_new(); /* create some physical memory */
    fprintf(stderr, "From Mem: %x\n", pmem->val);
......
}
```

Why is it that this fprintf prints out **From Mem: 4019cff4**, unless I uncomment the fprintf line in pmem_new(), at which the both correctly print out **From Mem:0**

Comment: you return a poiner to a local variable that is destroyed at the end of the function. therefore the returned pointer is invalid.

Answer (score 4):

Because `pmem` is no longer pointing to a valid memory region after `pmem_new()` exits.  What you are seeing is undefined behavior.

```
 pmem_p pmem_new() {
  pmem_s pmems;
  pmem_p pmem = &pmems;
  pmem->val = 0;
  //printf(stderr, "From Mem: %x\n", pmem->val);
  return pmem;
}
```

Here, you allocate `pmems` on the "stack" inside the scope of the function `pmem_new()`. With "stack allocation", the memory will become invalid once the program leaves the surrounding scope. Therefore, the pointer to `pmems` will become a **[dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer#Cause_of_dangling_pointers)** after leaving the function `pmem_new()`.

You could solve it by allocating the memory on the "heap", which the memory won't be destroyed unless you manually do so. In C this is done by the `malloc` method:

```
pmem_p pmem_new_correct() {
  pmem_p pmem = malloc(sizeof(*pmem));
  pmem->val = 0;
  return pmem;
}
```

But you have to remember to free this pointer, otherwise you'll create a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

```
int main() {
  pmem_p pmem = pmem_new();
  fprintf(stderr, "From Mem: %x\n", pmem->val);
  ......
  free(pmem);
}
```

(See also [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap) for stack vs heap.)

Comment: @user1706394: No, not globals, see KennyTM's update (or create a structure variable (not just a pointer) in main, which is different than a global).